# Subscribing to paramMap breaks routing example?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-router

When switching from `params` to `paramMap` in this [stackblitz hello component routing example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqt4jy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the routing no longer displays the correct result in the router outlet.

I changed the original `ngOnInit` code in `hello-component.ts` to this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params =>
     this.name = params.get['name']
   )
 }
```

But still no love.  I have enable tracing turned on for the router.  Is there a way to see what the problem is?

Comment: Just change it from `params.get['name']` to `params.get('name')`, as get is a function

Comment: Geez - I gotta start zooming my stackblitz - thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parammap returns a map and not an object so you have to change your code to like this

`this.name = params.get('name')` to get name param from the map.

Check updated code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cunq7t?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Check this link for more information on how to use paramMap https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap